# How to find all files submitted by specific user

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is it possible to find all files submitted by someone ideally via P4V, otherwise P4.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you mean "check out"? Do you mean "look at commit logs"?

Comment: I want to find out all files submitted (committed) by a person.

Comment: People is abusing voting by voting it down and closing it. Stackoverflow not my favourite any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In P4V:

1. View->Submitted Changelists
2. In the Submitted pane, expand the "Filter"
3. Change the "User" filter to the user you are interested in.
4. Clear the "Workspace" filter.

Comment: And in the command line, for completeness, 'p4 changes -s submitted -u <user>'